# Conectar Eloquent ORM a MySQL por un puerto distinto de 3306

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

Tengo un par de conexiones a cada una de ellas va a una base de datos MySQL diferente, el asunto es que una se conecta a un servidor local a si misma, pero la otra va a un servidor remoto y bajo "otro puerto", manejo las conexiones así:

```
$capsule->addConnection([
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => LOCAL_DB_HST,
'database' => LOCAL_DB_NAM,
'username' => LOCAL_DB_USR,
'password' => LOCAL_DB_PWD,
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => ''
], "local");

$capsule->addConnection([
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => REMOTE_DB_HST,
'database' => REMOTE_DB_NAM,
'username' => REMOTE_DB_USR,
'password' => REMOTE_DB_PWD,
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => ''
], "remota");
```

Es importante aclarar que no estoy usando Eloquent como parte de Laravel ... sino como una implementación totalmente independiente.

El asunto es que el servidor remoto MySQL usa un puerto distinto de 3306 y no se como deirle a Eloquent que use otro puerto al momento de conectarse al servidor remoto en tanto conserve el puerto por defecto (3306) para la conexión local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca lo usé sin laravel, pero calculo que tiene que funcionar igual y si es así podés especificarle el puerto. 
  Sería algo así:

```
$capsule->addConnection([
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => REMOTE_DB_HST,
'port' => REMOTE_DB_PORT,
'database' => REMOTE_DB_NAM,
'username' => REMOTE_DB_USR,
'password' => REMOTE_DB_PWD,
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => ''
], "remota");
```

Dentro de Laravel la configuración de una base de datos mysql es así, quizá te ayude.

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Comment: Hola, gracias, realmente me fue muy útil, Lo implementé tal cual y me funcionó perfecto, disculpa que haya demorado tanto en contestar.

Comment: que bueno! es interesante que estes usando Eloquent fuera de Laravel

Comment: Utilizo Eloquent y Sentinel trabajando juntos fuera de Laravel, sobre PHP nativo ... desde hace casi 3 años, lo uso en aplicaciones muy sencillas pero que requieran buena gestion de datos y usuarios